# debug memory leaks on linux

Tags: linux, debugging, memory-leaks

I've got an application that was compiled without debugging information and I need to check memory leaks. Is there any way to do it in linux like I can do it in solaris with mdb + umem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Run it with valgrind (valgrind yourexecutable).